# defining selected items

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a multiselect tag, and would like for the items which are marked active in the db to be auto selected

i have this in the view:

```
<%= select_tag 'graph[]', options_for_select(@graphs.collect {|s| [s.name, s.id]}), :multiple => true, :class => "multiselect" %>
```

there's an attribute for each of these objects called active, which is a boolean, can anyone help in making it so that the ones with true are selected otherwise not?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<%= select_tag 'graph[]', options_for_select(@graphs.collect {|s| [s.name, s.id]},[array of ids]), :multiple => true, :class => "multiselect" %>
```

replace [array of ids] with your Boolean value array

Comment: I've tried this <code> <%= select_tag 'graph[]', options_for_select(@graphs.collect {|s| [s.name, s.id]}, :selected => @graphs.where('pie = 1').collect {|s| [s.name, s.id]}), :multiple => true, :class => "multiselect" %> but it doesn't select the items when it reloads. It does generate the pairs for the selected array as [["swdd", 21], ["wdwddwd", 22], ["2eeee", 23], ["qsqssqsq", 24], ["ds,bd,mbdv,m", 20], ["eeee", 25], ["smcmc", 19]], but doesn't show the selection

Comment: use this :selected => @graphs.where('pie = 1').collect {|s| [s.id]}

Comment: nope, still nothing. i have for options :[["abc", 23], ["ade", 24], ["bac", 25]] and for selected this one [[24]], so in theory it should work i suppose, but... it doesn't select the records